# How override grid.phtml Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, template-override

Which referenceBlock name i should set in own xml file to override template `Magento/CatalogWidget/view/frontend/templates/product/widget/content/grid.phtml`?

Comment: using theme or custom module ?

Comment: @RkRathod i want use custom theme, own phtml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if Your are doing this using custom module you can do this using preference

in your

> Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList" type="Vendor\Module\Block\CatalogWidget\Product\ProductsList"/>
```

> Vendor\Module\Block\CatalogWidget\Product\ProductsList.php

Now in

```
class ProductsList extends \Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList {

    protected function _construct()
    {
        // parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::product/widget/content/grid.phtml');
    }

}
```

Comment: i want use custom theme, own phtml file

Comment: not working bro ..

Answer (score 0):

**Copy This File :-**

```
module-catalog-widget/view/frontend/templates/product/widget/content/grid.phtml
```

**To This :-**

```
yourtheme/Magento_CatalogWidget/templates/product/widget/content/grid.phtml
```

**And Change As Per Your Requirement.**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102680/discussion-on-answer-by-rk-rathod-how-override-grid-phtml-magento-2).